# ASP.net application not able to launch an exe because of IIS7

Tags: iis-7, asp.net-authorization

My asp.net application is trying to execute another exe . This was working fine on IIS 6 but its not working in IIS7. I have given the application pool full control of the directory conataining the exe . Still it gives an authorization error. Any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: How do you launch the exe? Which is the user? How is your application pool configured? Did you think of 64 vs. 32 Bit?